# How can I create deadlock on one table on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

How can I create deadlock on one table on MySQL ? I have ASP.NET application on production server and my command returns null instead particular row on table because table have particular rows. Some developers suggested that this behaviour is because of deadlock. How can I cause deadlock on my local PC environment? I have MySQL database on my local PC. How should I set deadlock on particular table. I want to deadlock select command? Can somebody give me MySQL command line example?

Comment: It requires *two* different transactions, acquiring locks in an 'inverse' order to cause a [True Deadlock](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/28/how-to-deal-with-mysql-deadlocks/). Also, a Deadlock will result in 1) a SQL Error - which is not "returns null", if code munge that result to "null" then the code is broken and does not honor a Dead Lock, see link above; or 2) a 'Non-Terminating Command' - although this is really a Livelock situation, and not a True Deadlock.

Comment: So tldr; *neither* a Deadlock (nor a Livelock) results in a "null value" from MySQL. Other race-conditions or violated assumptions might..

Comment: http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/What-Is-Dead-Lock.html